# Calling a variable to a different route not working in nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have my app.js set up like this:

**app.js**

```js
 var express = require('express');
 var socket_io = require("socket.io");
 var app = express();
 
 //Our route variables.
 var routes = require('./routes/index');
 var users = require('./routes/users');
 var work = require('./routes/work');
 

 // Socket.io
 var io = socket_io();
 app.io = io;

 var playground = require('./routes/playground')(io);

 //CODE I WANT MOVED TO playground.js!
 //Socket IO playground
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('a user connected');
   socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
     io.emit('chat message', {
       message: msg.message,
       nickname: msg.nickname
     });
   });

   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
     console.log('a user disconnected');
   });
 });
```

I was told I could send .io to my route **playground.js** like this:

`var playground = require('./routes/playground')(io);`

However I get the following error **cannot call method of 'IndexOf' undefined**

I do not want my socket.io code to be in app,js because I don't want app.js to become messy. (The code will grow overtime) I only want to use socket.io in playground.js because all of my test apps will be there. Please let me know if I can make this more clear

**playground.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


module.exports = function(io) {
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("connection made!");
  });
};

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('playground');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you add `var playground....` to your `app.js` code. I want to see where you are calling it.

Comment: Is there a `module.exports` defined in the `playground` route? Does it take in an argument in the function definition? e.g. `module.exports = function (io) {...]`

Comment: @amingilani Yes, but im getting the error before I even move into playground.js

Comment: I was editing my previous comment, before you answered, sorry. Does the function definition take the `io` argument? And you're certain that your path is correct?

Comment: @amingilani Yes, the path is correct or the route wouldn't work and I'd get an error that the path could not be found.

Comment: @Tony, btw, pass the `app` in as well `require('./routes/playground')(app, io);` in `app.js` and add `app.use('/', router);` in the `playground` route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78289/discussion-between-amingilani-and-tony).

Answer (score 1):

In your `playground.js` the last line `module.exports = router;` supersedes the previous `module.exports` declaration.
Try:

```
//routes/playground.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


module.exports = function(app, io) {
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("connection made!");
  });
};

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('playground');

app.use('/', router);
});
```

and try `require('./routes/playground')(app, io);` in your app.s

Comment: debug (dispatching %s %s' req.method, req.url)
                                           ^
Cannot read property of method unefined